# Does the ImageMagick for iOS support converting jpeg images to GIF ?

Tags: iphone, ios, imagemagick

Does the ImageMagick for iOS support converting jpeg images to GIF? How to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, ImageMagick does support GIF creation on iOS, even though their [website](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#iOS) clearly states it only supports png, jpeg and tiff on iOS. I haven't found any source of this worth linking and the other link mentioned below is no longer existing, so good luck with that.

Comment: ImageMagick actually does support gif and animated gif creation on iOS

Answer (score 2):

GIFS are "*inherently supported in ImageMagick*", according to [comments here](http://www.cloudgoessocial.net/2011/03/21/im-xcode4-ios4-3/).

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118072425/http://brainbowapps.com/articles/2010/using-imagemagick-to-create-animated-gifs-on-the-iphone.html) describes how to export an animated GIF from UIImage source using ImageMagick on iOS that you can use as a starting point.

```
MagickWand *mw = NewMagickWand();
MagickSetFormat(mw, "gif");
```

Comment: Article no longer available

Comment: Updated article link to archive version.